# asp.net layout managers or layout controls

Tags: asp.net, css

I'm a long time winforms developer and one of the things I really liked was the layout manager controls they had like flowlayoutpanel or gridlayout. unfortunately these don't seem to exist in asp.net or do they?

I'm in the process of modifying my existing asp.net website to use css instead of tables, but when I go into the visual studio design mode it looks terrible.

It's really difficult to wrap my head around all these floats, div:clears and css tricks and then test and retest in every browser. Surely there must be a better way. Ideally a layout manager control which would display properly in design mode, act as a container, be lightweight, and use smart enough to emit tables or css depending on the browser abilities.

does such a control exist as part of asp.net, open source, or commercial add-on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using tables instead of DIVs and css can certainly help with laying things out (a lot of people will think this is bad practice, but its works)

Also, have a look at the asp.net Repeater and ListView components. The ListView is very good in that you have a lot of control over the layout and the rendered html, I would look at that.

Comment: I have tried to emulate tables manually use divs and float but its very difficult and renders different depending on browser. thats why I was hoping there would be layout managers like winforms because my page is dynamic and component need to resize and sometimes wrap when the user resizes the page. so I cant use absolute positioning.

Answer (score 0):

First thing - don't rely on the VS Designer.  It's not a browser.  Because each browser implements css in potentially different ways, your only option is to test in the browsers that you think your target market will use.

At first, css positioning can seem a bit confusing, but if you stick with it, you will be able to wrap your head around it.  There is no such control as you describe that I know of. CSS is part of a web developers required learning, just as SQL is if you need to use a database etc.